# Create Func<T,Bool> At runtime

Tags: c#-4.0, runtime, boolean, func

I have two classes: Role and CustomRole

```
public class CustomRole
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int MyRole { get; set; }
}
```

at compile time I have a delegate like this:

```
Func<CustomRole, bool> Del = o => o.RoleId > 0;
```

The problem is at runtime I need to create one more delegate with same condition but table name is changed

```
Func<Role, bool> Del1 = o => o.RoleId > 0;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have both Role and CustomRole implement a IRole interface that includes the RuleId property, then make your delegate use IRole.

If that is not an option, you could look into duck typing.

Comment: yeah that is the very fine answer,but the problem is Role class is generated by ORM(Ado.Entity FrameWork).i cannot modifie this class

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using reflection to get the property value:

```
Func<object, bool> del = o => (int)o.GetType().GetProperty("RoleId").GetValue(o, null) > 0;
```

As you're using Entity Framework you could probably do this as well:

```
Func<EntityObject, bool> del = o => (int)o.GetType().GetProperty("RoleId").GetValue(o, null) > 0;
```